# Understanding how the yield impacts the return value in a JS generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Let's say I have some function as follows:

```js
function *hello(x) { // define generator
  while (x < 7) {
 console.log(`before: ${x}`)
    x += yield x + 1; // generator object will have value x + 1, then next step of generator has value x + x and not x + x + 1
 console.log(`after: ${x}`)
  }
  return x; 
}
var world = hello(3);
console.log( world.next(2) ); 
console.log( world.next(2) ); 
console.log( world.next(2) );
console.log( world.next(2) );

// before: 3
// {value: 4, done: false}
// after: 5
// before: 5
// {value: 6, done: false}
// after: 7
// {value: 7, done: true}
// {value: undefined, done: true}
```

I can see that the line with the `yield` returns a generator object with a value of `x + 1`, but the actual value of `x` is only increased by `x`, not `x+1`, as can be seen by the values in the `before` and `after` console logs. Why is it that the value of `x`, which comes to the right hand side of the `yield` is added to the current value of `x`, but the `+ 1` is not? I know that the value of `x` is what is being added, because if I change the value passed to the generator object in the `next` function, the before and after values reflect how much `x` was incremented by.

```js
function *hello(x) { // define generator
  while (x < 7) {
 console.log(`before: ${x}`)
    x += yield x + 1; // generator object will have value x + 1, then next step of generator has value x + x and not x + x + 1
 console.log(`after: ${x}`)
  }
  return x; 
}
var world = hello(3);
console.log( world.next(1) ); 
console.log( world.next(1) ); 
console.log( world.next(1) );
console.log( world.next(1) );

// before: 3
// {value: 4, done: false}
// after: 4
// before: 4
// {value: 5, done: false}
// after: 5
// before: 5
// {value: 6, done: false}
// after: 6
// before: 6
// {value: 7, done: false}
// after: 7
// {value: 7, done: true}
// {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the expression:

```
x += yield x + 1;
```

is *not* `x + 1`. The value `x + 1` is what is yielded to the caller. The value of `yield` in the generator is whatever was passed in. In this case, it's always `1` because that's what is being passed to it with:

```
world.next(1)
```

A generator stops as soon as it hits the [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) so in this case

```
x += yield x + 1;
```

You can think of it as working like:

```
yield x + 1; // pass this value to the called

[Pause]

[Next call from  world.next(1)]

x = 1 // value passed in from caller
```

Comment: So, after the expression `x+1` is yielded to the generator object, it's basically as if everything on the right hand side of `yield` is dropped when code execution is resumed?

Comment: Yes, @emijune the right hand side is not part of the value of the expression. You can think of yield as similar to returning the expression to the right. Then waiting for input to pass to the left.

Comment: Got it. So, hypothetically if I did want to increment by x + 1, I would modify the statement to `yield x += x + 1` rather than ` x += yield x + 1`. That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Yes @emijune, there is also the option of passing x back into the generator from outside: `let g =  hello(0); world = g.next(world.value)` while `world.done` is false. This will pass `x+1` back into the generator.